# Help with proof that $E(G|a < G < b) \lt E(H|a < H < b)$ for truncated normal distributions

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Consider two independent normally distributed random variables with equal standard deviations, $G\sim N (\mu_{G}, \sigma)$ and $H\sim N (\mu_{H}, \sigma)$ that are truncated between points $a$ and $b$. If $\mu_{G} \lt \mu_{H}$, prove that $E(G|a \lt G \lt b) \lt E(H|a \lt H \lt b)$.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution), the PDF of a normal distribution $X$ truncated between $a$ and $b$ is:

\begin{equation}
f_{X}(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\beta\right) - \Phi\left(\alpha\right)}
\end{equation}

where $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ are the PDF and CDF of the standard normal distribution evaluated at $x$, and $\alpha = \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$ and $\beta = \frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}$. The expected value of a truncated normal distribution is:

\begin{equation}
E(X | a < X < B) = \mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(\alpha)- \phi(\beta)}{\Phi(\beta) - \Phi(\alpha)}
\end{equation}

So far I have tried putting $E(G|a \lt G \lt b) \lt E(H|a \lt H \lt b)$ into Mathematica and reducing the inequality, but Mathematica can't handle these equations. I'm not sure how to go about solving these by hand. Other thoughts that I've had are that it would be equivalent to prove that $f_{G}(a) \gt f_{H}(a)$ or $f_{G}(b) \lt f_{H}(b)$. Does anyone have any possible directions forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I managed to prove this - the proof is detailed [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04358).